# Discord - Saving all messages of someone else's server

Tags: python, discord, discord.py, bots

I am trying to develop a bot that saves all the messages of a server that I have joined. I would like to know if anyone as done this before and how should I go about doing it?

I have gone through the API, but couldn't find a way to achieve this.

Comment: "of a server that I have joined". Your bot is **required** to have joined the server as well, in order for your bot to interact with the server in any way.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can download all messages on a server by basically looping through all channels, and retrieving the messages. Depending on the amount of messages, this can take minutes upto hours. And you will probably get flagged by Discord's anti-spam system.

```
for textChannel in guild.text_channels:
    messagesInChannel = await textChannel.history(limit=None).flatten() # None for all messages
    with open(textChannel.name + "_messages.txt", "w+") as f:
        for message in messagesInChannel:
            f.write(message.content + "\n")
```

Comment: So, I need to add the bot to the guild first, right?

Comment: Yes, you will need to do that

Comment: Okay, Thank you for your response.

Answer (score 0):

It's not a bot, but you can get all the messages of someone else's server
[How to get a token and link](https://i.stack.imgur.com/TppQl.png)

```
import requests, json

header = {
    "authorization": "token",
}

req = requests.get(f"https://discord.com/api/v9/channels/900478091078537248/messages?limit=50", headers=header)

for string in req.json():
    print( string["content"] )
```

Move around the chat

```
/api/v9/channels/900478091078537248/messages?before=920568383970377738&limit=50
/api/v9/channels/900478091078537248/messages?before=919896427352686603&limit=50
```